# Python : retrieve variable/result from C module

Tags: python, c, return-value

i have a need to use SPI in Raspberry, and its working with this approach, however its prints the result from the reading of the SPI bus to screen, something i don't want.
Python calls the Compiled C module with the data i want to send, but i want to receive inside python the response, not to the screen.
I never use C and i'm a little shallow in this language, so can someone tell me an option?
i read something about getting cout and fopen but would like to find if there is something more incorporated into python?
Any chance instead of printing the result to screen to do a return result from function or something?

Thank you.

C module:

```
#include <Python.h>
#include "structmember.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <linux/spi/spidev.h>
#include <linux/types.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>

#define ARRAY_SIZE(a) (sizeof(a) / sizeof((a)[0]))
#define MAXPATH 16

PyDoc_STRVAR(SPI_module_doc,
    "This module defines an object type that allows SPI transactions\n"
    "on hosts running the Linux kernel. The host kernel must have SPI\n"
    "support and SPI device interface support.\n"
    "All of these can be either built-in to the kernel, or loaded from\n"
    "modules.\n"
    "\n"
    "Because the SPI device interface is opened R/W, users of this\n"
    "module usually must have root permissions.\n");

typedef struct {
    PyObject_HEAD

    int fd; /* open file descriptor: /dev/spi-X.Y */
    uint8_t mode;   /* current SPI mode */
    uint8_t bpw;    /* current SPI bits per word setting */
    uint32_t msh;   /* current SPI max speed setting in Hz */
} SPI;

static PyObject *
SPI_new(PyTypeObject *type, PyObject *args, PyObject *kwds)
{
    SPI *self;
    if ((self = (SPI *)type->tp_alloc(type, 0)) == NULL)
        return NULL;

    self->fd = -1;
    self->mode = 0;
    self->bpw = 0;
    self->msh = 0;

    Py_INCREF(self);
    return (PyObject *)self;
}

PyDoc_STRVAR(SPI_close_doc,
    "close()\n\n"
    "Disconnects the object from the interface.\n");


static PyObject *SPI_close(SPI *self)
{
    if ((self->fd != -1) && (close(self->fd) == -1)) {
        PyErr_SetFromErrno(PyExc_IOError);
        return NULL;
    }

    self->fd = -1;
    self->mode = 0;
    self->bpw = 0;
    self->msh = 0;

    Py_INCREF(Py_None);
    return Py_None;
}

PyDoc_STRVAR(SPI_transfer_doc,
    "transfer([values]) -> [values]\n\n"
    "Perform SPI transaction.\n"
    "CS will be released and reactivated between blocks.\n"
    "delay specifies delay in usec between blocks.\n");



static PyObject* SPI_transfer(SPI *self, PyObject *args)
{
    uint8_t bits = 8;
    int ret = 0;
    char* list;
    int length_list = 1;
    uint16_t delay = 5;
    uint32_t speed = 500000;
    int i=0;

    PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "s|i:transfer", &list, &length_list);

    char hexbyte[3] = {0};
    uint8_t tx[length_list];
    for (i=0; i < (length_list); i++){

        //should grab first two characters

        //Data Transfer from String list to 2 byte string
        hexbyte[0] = list[2*i];
        hexbyte[1] = list[(2*i)+1];

        //Passing the 2 byte string into a Hex unsigned int 8-bit and then printing result
        sscanf(hexbyte, "%X", &tx[i]);
    }


    for (ret=0; ret<ARRAY_SIZE(tx); ret++){

    }
    puts("\n");

    uint8_t rx[ARRAY_SIZE(tx)];

    /*This is the transfer part, and sets up
    the details needed to transfer the data*/
    struct spi_ioc_transfer tr = {
        .tx_buf = (unsigned long)tx,
        .rx_buf = (unsigned long)rx,
        .len = ARRAY_SIZE(tx),
        .delay_usecs = delay,
        .speed_hz = speed,
        .bits_per_word = bits,
    };

    //The Actuall Transfer command and data, does send and receive!! Very important!
    ret = ioctl(self->fd, SPI_IOC_MESSAGE(1), &tr);
    if (ret < 1)
        printf("ERROR: Can't send spi message");


    //This part prints the Received data of the SPI transmission of equal size to TX
    for (ret = 0; ret < ARRAY_SIZE(tx); ret++) {
        if (!(ret % 6))
            puts("");
        printf("%.2X ", rx[ret]);
    }
    puts("");

    Py_INCREF(list);
    return list;

}

PyDoc_STRVAR(SPI_open_doc,
    "open(bus, device)\n\n"
    "Connects the object to the specified SPI device.\n"
    "open(X,Y) will open /dev/spidev-X.Y\n");


static PyObject *SPI_open(SPI *self, PyObject *args, PyObject *kwds)
{
    int bus, device;
    char path[MAXPATH];
    uint8_t tmp8;
    uint32_t tmp32;
    static char *kwlist[] = {"bus", "device", NULL};
    if (!PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords(args, kwds, "ii:open", kwlist, &bus, &device))
        return NULL;
    if (snprintf(path, MAXPATH, "/dev/spidev%d.%d", bus, device) >= MAXPATH) {
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_OverflowError,
            "Bus and/or device number is invalid.");
        return NULL;
    }
    if ((self->fd = open(path, O_RDWR, 0)) < 0) {
        printf("can't open device");
        abort();
    }
    if (ioctl(self->fd, SPI_IOC_RD_MODE, &tmp8) == -1) {
        printf("can't get spi mode");
        abort();
    }
    self->mode = tmp8;
    if (ioctl(self->fd, SPI_IOC_RD_BITS_PER_WORD, &tmp8) == -1) {
        printf("can't get bits per word");
        abort();
    }
    self->bpw = tmp8;
    if (ioctl(self->fd, SPI_IOC_RD_MAX_SPEED_HZ, &tmp32) == -1) {
        printf("can't get max speed hz");
        abort();
    }
    self->msh = tmp32;

    Py_INCREF(Py_None);
    return Py_None;
}

static int SPI_init(SPI *self, PyObject *args, PyObject *kwds)
{
    int bus = -1;
    int client = -1;
    static char *kwlist[] = {"bus", "client", NULL};

    if (!PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords(args, kwds, "|ii:__init__",
            kwlist, &bus, &client))
        return -1;

    if (bus >= 0) {
        SPI_open(self, args, kwds);
        if (PyErr_Occurred())
            return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}


static PyMethodDef SPI_module_methods[] = {
   { NULL },
};

PyDoc_STRVAR(SPI_type_doc,
    "SPI([bus],[client]) -> SPI\n\n"
    "Return a new SPI object that is (optionally) connected to the\n"
    "specified SPI device interface.\n");

static PyMethodDef SPI_methods[] = {
   {"open", (PyCFunction)SPI_open, METH_VARARGS | METH_KEYWORDS, 
        SPI_open_doc},
   {"close", (PyCFunction)SPI_close, METH_NOARGS,
        SPI_close_doc},
   {"transfer", (PyCFunction)SPI_transfer, METH_VARARGS, 
        SPI_transfer_doc},
    {NULL},
};

static PyTypeObject SPI_type = {
    PyObject_HEAD_INIT(NULL)
    0,              /* ob_size */
    "SPI",          /* tp_name */
    sizeof(SPI),    /* tp_basicsize */
    0,              /* tp_itemsize */
    0,              /* tp_dealloc */
    0,              /* tp_print */
    0,              /* tp_getattr */
    0,              /* tp_setattr */
    0,              /* tp_compare */
    0,              /* tp_repr */
    0,              /* tp_as_number */
    0,              /* tp_as_sequence */
    0,              /* tp_as_mapping */
    0,              /* tp_hash */
    0,              /* tp_call */
    0,              /* tp_str */
    0,              /* tp_getattro */
    0,              /* tp_setattro */
    0,              /* tp_as_buffer */
    Py_TPFLAGS_DEFAULT,     /* tp_flags */
    SPI_type_doc,           /* tp_doc */
    0,              /* tp_traverse */
    0,              /* tp_clear */
    0,              /* tp_richcompare */
    0,              /* tp_weaklistoffset */
    0,              /* tp_iter */
    0,              /* tp_iternext */
    SPI_methods,    /* tp_methods */
    0,              /* tp_members */
    0,              /* tp_getset */
    0,              /* tp_base */
    0,              /* tp_dict */
    0,              /* tp_descr_get */
    0,              /* tp_descr_set */
    0,              /* tp_dictoffset */
    (initproc)SPI_init,     /* tp_init */
    0,              /* tp_alloc */
    SPI_new,            /* tp_new */
};

#ifndef PyMODINIT_FUNC  /* declarations for DLL import/export */
#define PyMODINIT_FUNC void
#endif

PyMODINIT_FUNC initspi(void)
{
    PyObject* m;

    if (PyType_Ready(&SPI_type) < 0)
        return;

    m = Py_InitModule3("spi", SPI_module_methods, SPI_module_doc);
    Py_INCREF(&SPI_type);
    PyModule_AddObject(m, "SPI", (PyObject *)&SPI_type);
}
```

And python script:

```
#Python example for SPI bus, written by Brian Hensley
#This script will take any amount of Hex values and determine
#the length and then transfer the data as a string to the "spi" module

import spi
from time import sleep

#At the beginning of the program open up the SPI port.
#this is port /dev/spidevX.Y
#Being called as as spi.SPI(X,Y)
a = spi.SPI(0,0)

print "PY: initialising SPI mode, reading data, reading length . . . \n"

#This is my data that I want sent through my SPI bus
data = ["53484f5728677275706f293b3b0d"]

#Calculates the length, and devides by 2 for two bytes of data sent.
length_data = len(data[0])/2
i=0
#transfers data string
while True:
    a.transfer(data[0], length_data)
    i=i+1
    print i
    sleep(0.5)
#At the end of your program close the SPI port  
a.close()
```

Comment: This piece of C code is badly written.  In addition to dumping random stuff to stdout and abort()ing in case of error, it leaks memory (because of mistakes in the reference count handling).  It can be fixed but it's some effort.  If you're not too familiar with C, would it help if instead I suggested to look at [CFFI](http://cffi.readthedocs.org)?